# How do i insert List<Item?> to a List<Item> in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to put list of type List<Item?> into another list of type List in kotlin.

```
suspend fun insertNotifLocal(list: List<NotificationItems?>) = viewModelScope.async(IO){
    repository?.insertNotifLocal(list)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do looking at the code snippet but based on the title I can give some input:

If you have a `List<Any?>` and want to pass it as an argument for parameter: `List<Any>` you have to ensure that the list does not contain null anymore, e.g. with `filterNotNull`:

```
fun process(any: List<Any>): Int = any.size

fun main() {
    val nullableList: List<Any?> = listOf(null, 2, "two")
    process(nullableList.filterNotNull())
}
```

Comment: ahh so the question mark in "<Any?>" means that the list is a nullable, so it needs to be filtered. Thank you s1m0nw1